# Mask single column in datatable in C#

Tags: c#

I have datatable to view in gridview. Now i need to mask 1st 6 digit of "AdminNumber" column content to "XXXXXX895".

DataTable Input:

```
AdminNumber   Name
245637895     sham
124563789     Ram
```

I need Datatable output as:

```
AdminNumber  Name
XXXXXX895    Sham
XXXXXX789    Ram
```

I have tried, but iam getting format the string option:

```
  gridview.DataSource = dtSource;
       gridview.Columns[0].FormatString = "######";
```

Iam getting wrong output as

```
AdminNumber  Name
 XXXXXXXXX    Sham
 XXXXXXXXX    Ram
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `CellFormatting` event:

```
private void gridview_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Value != null) 
    {
        string adminNumber  = e.Value.ToString();
        int length = Math.Min(6, adminNumber.Length);
        adminNumber =  new string('X', length) + adminNumber.Substring(length);
        e.Value = adminNumber;
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Deleted mine, because it doesn't make sense to iterate cells to assign value. Cell formatting is more elegant approach to format columns instead of user defined function `+1` to you.. Today I learnt `CellFormatting` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct in data base select query like this:

```
select stuff(column_name, 1, 6, '######') from table_name
```

and then bind this data table in gridview.