# mask whole single columns in datatable using c#

Tags: c#

Datatable contains multiple columns and it will be displayed in gridview. Now i need to mask 1st 6 digit of 1 entire column of "Number" content format like "XXX-XX-7895".

DataTable Input:

```
Number       FName   LastName
781637895     sham    C
558563789     Ram     M
```

I need Datatable output as:

```
Number       FName   LastName
XXX-XX-7895     sham    C
XXX-XX-3789     Ram     M
```

I have tried using **CellFormatting** event, it has been achieved using without "-" character. I need "-" character to be included.

```
private void gridview_transformation_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
           if (e.ColumnIndex == 7 )
            {
                string adminNumber = e.CellElement.Value.ToString();
                int length = Math.Min(5, adminNumber.Length);
                adminNumber = new string('X', length) + adminNumber.Substring(length);
                e.CellElement.Value = adminNumber;

        }
```

ouput which i got(Wrong Output)

```
Number       FName   LastName
XXXXX7895     sham    C
XXXXX3789     Ram     M
```

Kindly help to get correct format.

Comment: It would have been better to edit or comment on your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50644079/mask-single-column-in-datatable-in-c-sharp) than duplicating it.

Comment: So I assume length is supposed to be variable? Then what are the rules for when to add a `-`? If it's not, then `adminNumber = "XXX-XX-" + adminNumber.Substring(length);` would do the trick.

Comment: Many databases provide real masking behaviour. For example, SQL Server 2016 and later provides [Dynamic Data Masking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/dynamic-data-masking?view=sql-server-2016)

Comment: Otherwise, if the value is an integer you can use `%10000` to get the last 4 digits and use a format string to display the `X`s. Eg `(781637895%10000).ToString("XXX-XX-0")` will return `XXX-XX-7895`. The same format string works with `String.Format`, eg `String.Format("XXX-XX-{0}", thatNumber %10000)`

Comment: Many databases provide real masking behaviour,but i need to do in c#

Answer (score 1):

```
int length = Math.Min(4, adminNumber.Length);
adminNumber = "XXX-XX-" + adminNumber.Substring(length);
```

Comment: it keeps on appending the value as XXX-XX-XXX-XX-XXX-XX-XXX-XX-7895